# ASP.NET Core scaffolding generators

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, aurelia

Does anyone know of a scaffolding generator I can use to generate ASP.NET Core apps in Angular or Aurelia that will work in Visual Studio 2015?

The 'dotnet new' and yeoman generators are great, but they scaffold applications in VS 2017 format.

I would like to use VS 2015 and I would really like to scaffold my app properly, like those generators do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found one for Aurelia on GitHub:

[Skeleton-navigation for Aurelia](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation)

It has scaffolding for 6 different types of apps - 3 using ES2015 and 3 using TypeScript. The ASP.NET Core skeletons set up the project in VS 2015 format with a project.json. I needed to tweak it just a little because I was using a later version of ASP.NET Core and because I wanted to target the .NET Framework 4.6 rather than targeting .NET Core for the base framework. But the scaffold is a good one and the docs are good too.

EDIT: To be clear this is not a generator, per se. It is a GitHub repository that can be cloned or downloaded.

I still have not found anything for Angular though. If anyone knows of something for Angular, please chime in.

Thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

**This works for both VS2015 and older pre-RC4 versions of .NET tooling**

You can use Yeoman generator.First, make sure to install: `.NET Core SDK 1.1` and `Node.js Version 6` (or Later).

To install the Yeoman Templates for this, open command prompt and run:

```
npm install -g yo generator-aspnetcore-spa
```

Then create a folder/directory for the project you want to create. cd into your project directory and run the Yeoman command below:

```
yo aspnetcore-spa
```

Yeoman will auto-fetch dependencies and packages for you.

To run your project, execute the following command within the project folder:

```
dotnet run
```