# What is Location for ASP.NET Core Razor Scaffolding templates in VS 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, t4scaffolding, asp.net-core-scaffolding

My intention is to customize default Razor templates for **ASP.NET Core 3.1**. To do so, I will add custom HTML to the **default T4 Razor templates** so that I don't have to update each generated view again and again. But I am unable to find the exact location for these templates.

I have tried the following links and googled it as well but I am unable to find the location of the template for **VS 2019** for **ASP.NET Core 3.1** - instead, I find for ASP.NET MVC4/5 with VS 2015/2017, etc.

It would be a great help if anyone can tell me about the **location of T4 Razor templates for ASP.NET Core 3.1 for VS 2019**

Some of the links:

[asp-net-core-custom-scaffolding-visual-studio-2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551175/asp-net-core-scaffolding-generators)

[asp-net-core-scaffolding-generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551175/asp-net-core-scaffolding-generators)

[asp-net-use-razor-to-generate-html-for-templates-in-a-single-page-app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/march/asp-net-use-razor-to-generate-html-for-templates-in-a-single-page-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382954/custom-scaffold-templates-in-asp-net-core?rq=1),and I do as `user3012633` said,
I can find templates in `C:\Users\{username}\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc\3.1.4\Templates`.

templates:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works.. I had come across this post but I don't know why I couldn't see v3.1 on the same location